# COM EXE Singleton - getting separate instance when client runs as admin

Tags: security, process, com, localserver

I need to share information (and ideally, send notifications) across multiple instances of various programs of ours running on the same desktop.

A standard ATL EXE server singleton seems to fit the scenario we have pretty well: clients can  create an object of this instance, register their information with it and/or query the information from others.

However, a client started "Run as Administrator" gets its own instance (and server process).

I almost expected that behavior, but I don't know what options I have to get this working.

---

(Preferrably, an instance running under the admin token should be able to exchange information with one that does not. Multiple users logged in at the same machine should not share information, though, but that's negotiable

I do see other options - windows user message broadcasts, a memory mapped file or even files on disk, but that would be much more complex.)

Comment: Obscure stuff, you ought to review the "OTS elevation" section in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you!   --- Obscure: well, I nocticed; seems like a normal question to me, which is a bit scary.